# how long we can execute prepared statement after prepared once?

Tags: mysql

********As i read out, I think whenever i need to perform any query again and again, ( a big no. of time) , prepared statement is best solution because it save time by not to parsed query again and again,***
I want to know after preapared once, how long i can execute prepared statement,
 suppose my window application have 10 different frame( window), so i can execute it from different frame,while declare in another frame,
what is the scope of prepared statement?
if for inserting millions of record (automatically)   ,if we use stored procedure so how it can spoil the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One prepared statement is valid through out one request. Different frames are separate requests, so the statement is not reused among them.

You have to bound values to a prepared object anyway, so this should be obvious.